# Demand-paging environment

Tags: operating-system, paging

In terms of programming techniques or type of data structures(in a user-level program), I was wondering if it would be better to use pointers and linked lists
or sequential search through an array or would it be better to use a binary tree search. I have a basic understanding of virtual memory management and would like to understand why one technique would be better than the other for implementing an efficient demand-paging environment considering that a page is loaded only on a reference to the instructions that it contains, the page fault rate is usually high when execution starts and the page fault rate decreases when the pages of the locality of reference are loaded.

Comment: It depends upon many factors. Is your data sorted? How large is it?

Comment: You question is not clear to me, can you explain a bit?

Comment: @Maharaj:  In a demand paging environment, a page is loaded only on a reference to the instructions that it contains.  Furthermore the page fault rate is usually high when execution starts and the page fault rate decreases when the pages of the locality of reference are loaded.  So based on these specifications, what would be the best data structure or programming technique?